# Advice on the DB structure of a firebase Chat application

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization, nosql

I have just started using firebase to build my first chat application (react native).
I am however slightly confused about the ideal structure my database should have.
The firebase docs suggest that the structure should be as normalized as possible, but the type of queries i have access to make it look like normalizing the data would impact performance.

Just a quick example that fits my use case:
My fast, denormalized structure would be:

```
{
  "workgroups": {
    "40": {
      "id": "40",
      "name": "workgroup 1 name",
      "messages": {
        "message-1-id": {
          "id": "message-1-id",
          "text": "Message 1 text",
          "user": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "User 1 name",
            "avatar": "http://user1avatar.com"
          }
        },
        "message-2-id": {
          "id": "message-2-id",
          "text": "Message 2 text",
          "user": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "User 1 name",
            "avatar": "http://user1avatar.com"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The obvious downside being that if a user changes his avatar only the new messages will display it.

My normalized structure would be:

```
{
  "workgroups": {
    "40": {
      "id": "40",
      "name": "workgroup 1 name",
      "messages": {
        "message-1-id": {
          "id": "message-1-id",
          "text": "Message 1 text",
          "user": "1"
        },
        "message-2-id": {
          "id": "message-2-id",
          "text": "Message 2 text",
          "user": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "User 1 name",
      "avatar": "http://user1avatar.com"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "User 2 name",
      "avatar": "http://user2avatar.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I have to fetch all messages for a certain place and each message would
need to have the senders avatar and name connected to it.
Is the denormalized structure still the better option?

If the normalized structure would still be prefered then how should i join the tables?
My first attempt was to fetch all messages in a place and then fetch each user for each message 
but i doubt that would be the best solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but I suggest you do some short experiments to test your use cases. I restructured my data several times before I found an approach that worked for me, but testing and experimenting is the best way to find out if you have any bottlenecks. Also, once you have a structure you can work with, don't forget to create indexes for the items you want to query. And if you are thinking of adding security rules later, do some early experiments to understand how that will affect your data/queries. Good luck!

Comment: Yes i will definitely do a few experiments before building around one definite structure. Much better to plan it out properly than to keep changing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say what the best approach is since we don't know the end game of your application is. Will you have a need to search for messages, users etc? Will you want to list users?

Since you mention:

> "if a user changes his avatar only the new messages will display it"

you have already answered you own question I think. You should normalize the data so messages and users are separate.

Firebase isn't a relational DB so you wouldn't join any tables. You query the messages. Once you get the first message you can start to query users from the user id in the message. You'll end up querying once for messages and 1 query for each user you need. You can be smart about querying for users and only query users if you haven't already queried them.

You can check out [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY) on how to do "join" in Firebase as opposed to how you'd do it in SQL

Comment: To answer your questions my goal here is to build a simple chat which will also have images and videos. Each chatroom/workgroup has multiple users but no searching or user list is required.

So from what i understand from your answer is that i should prioritize the normalized data structure over the denormalized one and rather work on finding an efficient method to access the sender of a message through another query.

And yes i would keep a list of all fetched users in my state and only fetch a user object if it hasn't been fetched before.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes, go for normalized data in that case. Ps. don't use the Firebase database to store images/video. Have a look at Firebase storage instead. Then link to the storage path from your dataset (i.e. even more queries, but you gain other advantages) Ds